# Is there only single 'Gnana Saraswathi temple' In India?

Tags: temple, india, saraswati

When I search online, I can find only a single temple for **Ganana Saraswathi** in India. The temple is [located in Basar, Telangana](https://nirmal.telangana.gov.in/tourist-place/sri-gnana-saraswathi-devasthanam-basara/).

The legend of the temple is [mentioned on the temple website](http://www.basaratemple.org/legend.php)

> Legend suggest that Maharshi Veda Vyasa, the author of Mahabharata,
> came to the forests of Dandakaryana to meditate. He began meditating
> on the banks of the River Godavari and found the place to be very
> peaceful. The divine mother is believed to have appeared before the
> sage and ordained him to build temples for the Shakti trio: Maha
> Saraswathi, Maha Lakshmi and Maha Kali. The sage Veda Vyasa did so by
> bringing three handfuls of sand and sculpts out the figures. This
> place was initially named after Vyasa and was called "Vyasapuri".
> Later on it got took names Vasara and ultimately Basara/Basar.

I feel that there can be more temples that are not popular. Are there any other temples of Gnana Saraswathi in India?

Comment: sharda peetha is also a temple for mother Saraswati